# Bishop and queen endgame from a computer chess game

Tags: analysis, endgame, queen-and-bishop-endgame

```
[FEN "8/6pk/p4b1p/2B5/P3q2P/6P1/5P2/3Q2K1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Ba7 (1. h5)
```

This position happened in TCEC Season 15 Superfinal Stockfish vs Leela. In the game Stockfish played Ba7 and the game steered toward a draw , though in the end Stockfish won because a late Leela blunder. Can Stockfish win by force this ending? Crystal (7 man tablebases Stockfish , albeit with a slightly lesser depth) suggested h5. I am unable to analyze it with the modest instrument I have. May someone telling me if it is winnable by White , and , in case , with what move, please?

Comment: @BrianTowers there are some beautiful community rules available to anyone interested in reading them. We are glad to welcome new contributors, but only those willing to make the effort

Comment: As far as I know, Queen endgames tend to be hard to not draw, consider that except famous examples such as the Lucena, even rook Vs rook and pawn tend to be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Queen endings are among the most difficult.

We usually say "win by force" when there's a definite winning line. You're asking if White is certain to win, not at all certain.

A human player would look first to winning the  queenside pawn and then with an advantage on both wings, many chances to win. But while that pawn sits on a black square White can't coordinate force against it.

And I don't think White can try for a kingside initiative while the a-pawn has to be tended to. White doesn't want to move it to a5, where it's fixed and can be coordinated against, and it's always exposed to threats on a4.